# Why gcc duplicates rodata string for memcpy? How to avoid it?

Tags: c, string, gcc, duplicates, memcpy

For some reason, GCC duplicates content of const char string into separate rodata area, which I don't understand. 
I compile provided code:

```
static const char pattern[] = "[SOME TEST PATTERN TO CALCULATE SUM FROM] ";

static char tmpbuf[sizeof(pattern) + 1];

uint16_t sum(char *buf, int size)
{
    uint16_t ret = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        ret += buf[i];

    return ret;
}

void getPattern(char **retbuf)
{
    memcpy(tmpbuf, pattern, sizeof(tmpbuf) -1);
    *retbuf = tmpbuf;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    getPattern(&argv[0]);

    return sum((char *)pattern, sizeof(pattern) - 2) > 0;
}

void _exit(int status)
{
    while(1)
    {
        asm("nop");
    }
}
```

with arm gcc compiler, using command:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Os dbstr.c -o dbstr -Wl,-Map,"dbstr.map" -fdata-sections
```

In resulting binary, even if it is stripped, I find string:

```
"[SOME TEST PATTERN TO CALCULATE SUM FROM] "
```

duplicated.

Looking into symbol map, i find:

```
.rodata.pattern
                0x000087d8       0x2b ... ccumYoyx.o
.rodata.str1.1
                0x00008803       0x2b ... ccumYoyx.o
and
.bss.tmpbuf    0x00018ca0       0x2c ... ccumYoyx.o
```

symbol "pattern" is original array
symbol "str1" is duplicate
and symbol "tmpbuf" is target buffer, into which I want to copy "pattern".

Looking into generated assembly, I found that memcpy uses duplicate created by compiler:

```
getPattern:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
->  ldr r3, .L6
    push    {r4, lr}
    mov r2, #43
    mov r4, r0
    ldr r1, .L6+4
    mov r0, r3
    bl  memcpy
...

.L6:
    .word   .LANCHOR0
->  .word   .LC0
...
pattern:
    .ascii  "[SOME TEST PATTERN TO CALCULATE SUM FROM] \000"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",%progbits,1
.LC0: /*duplicate string*/
    .ascii  "[SOME TEST PATTERN TO CALCULATE SUM FROM] \000"
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 8-2018-q4-major) 8.2.1 20181213 (release) [gcc-8-branch revision 267074]"
```

I checked that it happens with arm-none-eabi-gcc versions from 6-2017-q1-update to 8-2018-q4-major (latest available on developer.arm.com).

I also tried using various optimizations. Duplicate does not occur only when using -O0. For others it does.

In bigger application, that this problem occured, it turned out that memcpy copied duplicate string instead of original - it was determined by substitution of original string in binary. I need memcpy to use original string.

Comment: You could try by declaring the `pattern` variable also as `volatile`, in order to prevent any optimization to it. It is perfectly legal to have it `const` and `volatile`, so the declaration would be: `static const volatile char pattern[] = "[SOME TEST PATTERN TO CALCULATE SUM FROM] ";`

Comment: You could try optimizing for size (`-Os`).  If that works, then there is probably a specific optimization option that controls this behavior (GCC optimization is highly tunable).

Comment: And to be clear, the problem here is that the binary is larger than it needs to be, yes?  If it produces incorrect behavior then we would want to see code that actually demonstrates such misbehavior in order to diagnose that problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger is right, in order to give a correct answer, we would need the actual problem and the code demonstrating it. Nevertheless, my comment applies when a `const` variable is not as `const` as the compiler might think. This may happen, for instance, when working with a uC which is able to erase part of its memory and replace it with other data. The compiler would not know this behaviour, since it is not standard C. This can be solved by using the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: @JohnBollinger actually the OP has `-Os` included in the command... or am I missing something?

Comment: I had overlooked that, @andreee.  I had also overlooked that the OP is looking at the object file, not the linked executable, which may also make a difference.

Comment: @LoPiTaL adding volatile to string declaration helps. The actual issue is that program tries to detect if this const string was substituted inside binary with something else, thus having duplicate resulted in either not detecting substitution, or modifying duplicate instead of original in binary. I assumed that there should be only one occurance of this string.

Comment: regarding: `void _exit(int status)`  the function: `_exit()` is a C library function.  Code should not be re-defining C library functions.  If you want to create a similar function, the name should be unique.  For instance: `myExit()`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can duplicate the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: Actuallly this is complete example. It lacks only including string.h and stdint.h compiles for both arm and x86 and shows the same result. Of course it will not run, it only reproduces 2 instances of the same string in binary.

Comment: @user3629249 _exit function is defined so that code compiles with arm-none-eabi gcc flavor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you observe is specified explicitly by the standard.  In

> ```
> static const char pattern[] = "[SOME TEST PATTERN TO CALCULATE SUM FROM] ";
> ```

you have a declaration of variable pattern and an initializer in the form of a string literal.  [Paragraph 6.4.5/6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6) of the standard specifies that

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to
>   each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal
>   or literals. ***The multibyte character sequence is then used to
>   initialize an array of static storage duration*** and length just
>   sufficient to contain the sequence.

(Emphasis added.) That the resulting array has static storage duration means that, at least in principle, memory must be reserved for it in the program.  This is what you are seeing in the form of `str1.1`.  But you are also using that string to initialize an array, so that array gets the same character sequence, and that also occupies memory in the binary because it, too, has static storage duration as a result of being declared at file scope.

In principle, GCC ought to be able to optimize away the extra array.  In particular, option `-fmerge-constants` should do this, but this is included at all optimization levels other than `-O0`, so it's surprising that you're not seeing such merging, but it's possible that the merging will be performed at link time, so that what you're seeing is a meaningless artifact of looking at the object file before linking.

You should also be able to avoid the copy by declaring `pattern` as a pointer instead of an array:

```
static const char * const pattern = "[SOME TEST PATTERN TO CALCULATE SUM FROM] ";
```

but **NOTE WELL** that although the result can be used in many of the same ways as the array version, it is not semantically identical.  You will see differences if you apply the `sizeof`, `*`, or `&`, or `_Alignof` operator to `pattern`.

---

Update:

Another, much uglier, workaround would be to avoid a string literal altogether, like so:

```
static const char pattern[] = {
        '[', 'S', 'O', 'M', 'E', ' ', 'T', 'E', 'S', 'T', ' ', 'P', 'A', 'T',
        'T', 'E', 'R', 'N', ' ', 'T', 'O', ' ', 'C', 'A', 'L', 'C', 'U', 'L',
        'A', 'T', 'E', ' ', 'S', 'U', 'M', ' ', 'F', 'R', 'O', 'M', ']', ' ', '\0' };
```

That leaves you with `pattern` as an array, not a pointer, and no separate array for a string literal.  It's ugly and more difficult to maintain, but converting from string literal form to that isn't hard -- it took me about 30 seconds to do that one.  If you do it, though, don't forget to add an explicit string terminator, as above.

Comment: This explains what is happening, but extra array is not optimized at link time. Adding explicitly -fmerge-constants does not have any effect. I have the same result with this code compiled for x86 - maybe it should be reported as a bug in GCC ?

Comment: Actually, declaring both arrays as non-static does not change anything - there are still two occurances in binary. Removing const sepcifier from pattern results in only single occurance of string in binary. Since adding volatile changes this behaviour, it looks more like some kind of optimization issue, rather than initialization.

Comment: The `static` keyword has nothing to do with it.  All file-scope declarations have static storage duration.  In conjunction with such a declaration, the `static` keyword specifies *internal linkage*.  (Different rules apply to block-scope variables.)

Comment: I cannot speak to why GCC is not merging the identical string constants when you use optimization flags that ought to have that effect (supposing, of course, that you indeed are looking at a binary created by a GCC run affected by those flags both at compile time and link time).  If GCC won't do it, however, then it doesn't really matter why, though you could consider filing a bug ticket.  I have added a second workaround, though "workaround" is a bit of an odd way to describe writing code that directly describes what you actually want.

Comment: Ok, second workaround works. Following this answer, second copy of string literal should occur whenever i initialize static storage duration char array with it. But when i remove getPattern function from code above, declaration remains the same, but only single occurance of this string remains in binary... I don't see any usage of this second string, since pattern symbol already is in the same section (rodata) as this auxilary string created by compiler, and already initialized at that.

Comment: Again, @xnomad37, I cannot speak to details of what optimizations GCC chooses to make, or under what conditions, or whether those details are intended or buggy.  What I can and primarily have spoken to is what the C language specifications have to say about your code.  Specifically, it *asks for* two arrays with identical contents.  If you want to explicitly avoid that, then one of the two alternatives I've presented should do so.  Otherwise, your compiler *may* remove the duplication, but that's between it and you.

Comment: So, having 2 instances of this string is what we should expect, and having only one is just a compilers "optimization"? It is confusing for me, that in some cases it occurs, and in other it doesn't. Still, this answer is the most reasonable of everything I can think of.

Comment: Yes, @xnomad37.  Your code specifies two arrays with the same content.  If you end up with only one in the binary then that's because the compiler optimized one of them away, which it is permitted, but not required, to do, provided that the optimized program produces the same observable behavior.